# Shortest path to solve a maze

Tags: java, maze

This class uses graphics to print a maze.  The program will be run 3 times.  After the first, I save a steps array that counts the number of times the character steps over a spot.  I then write this array to a file.  Before the next run, I open the file.  I need to use the contents of the file to "learn" where not to go for the next trial (ie. avoid dead ends, find quickest path to finish).

I have a method hasBadBranch() that I want to return true for all intersections that have branches (north, south, east, and west of the intersection) with "steps" > 1.  I'm getting array index out of bounds and the character no longer goes through the maze correctly when I add the hasBadBranch condition in my solve() method.  If anyone sees any flaws in my logic, I would greatly appreciate the feedback.  Thanks.

```
public class Maze extends JFrame {

    private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 255;
    private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 255;

    private char[][] maze = new char[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH];
    private int[][] steps = new int[MAX_HEIGHT][MAX_WIDTH];

    private Random random = new Random();
    private JPanel mazePanel = new JPanel();
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;
    private boolean step = false;

    private boolean timerFired = false;
    private Timer timer;
    private final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;

    private final int SPRITE_WIDTH = 25;
    private final int SPRITE_HEIGHT = 25;

    private BufferedImage mazeImage;
    private ImageIcon ground = new ImageIcon("sprites/ground.png");
    private ImageIcon wall1 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cactus.png");
    private ImageIcon wall2 = new ImageIcon("sprites/rock.png");
    private ImageIcon finish = new ImageIcon("sprites/well.png");
    private ImageIcon south1 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-forward-1.png");
    private ImageIcon south2 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-forward-2.png");
    private ImageIcon north1 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-back-1.png");
    private ImageIcon north2 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-back-2.png");
    private ImageIcon west1 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-left-1.png");
    private ImageIcon west2 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-left-2.png");
    private ImageIcon east1 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-right-1.png");
    private ImageIcon east2 = new ImageIcon("sprites/cowboy-right-2.png");

    private long startTime;
    private long currentTime;

    private static final int MAX_TIME = 500000;

    /**
     * Constructor for class Maze. Opens a text file containing the maze, then
     * attempts to solve it.
     *
     * @param fname String value containing the filename of the maze to open.
     */
    //Notes to user: 
    //delete steps.txt BEFORE testing begins and AFTER third run of program
    //use appropriate file paths
    public Maze(String fname) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        openMaze(fname);
        mazeImage = printMaze();

        readInFile();

        timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerHandler());     // setup a Timer to slow the animation down.
        timer.start();

        addWindowListener(new WindowHandler());     // listen for window event windowClosing

        setTitle("Cowboy Maze");
        setSize(width * SPRITE_WIDTH + 10, height * SPRITE_HEIGHT + 30);
        setVisible(true);

        add(mazePanel);
        setContentPane(mazePanel);

        solveMaze();
    }

    public void readInFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //Note to user: adjust file path accordingly
        File stepsFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Ashley Bertrand\\Desktop\\Data Structures\\Lab6\\mazeStartSourceMazesGraphics\\steps.txt");

        if (stepsFile.isFile()) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stepsFile);
            int lineCount = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] currentLine = scanner.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < currentLine.length; i++) {
                    steps[lineCount][i] = Integer.parseInt(currentLine[i]);
                }
                lineCount++;
            }

            System.out.println("Contents of steps.txt:");
            for (int m = 0; m < width; m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < height; n++) {
                    System.out.print(steps[m][n]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Running first trial so steps.txt does not exist");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called from the operating system. If no command line arguments are
     * supplied, the method displays an error message and exits. Otherwise, a
     * new instance of Maze() is created with the supplied filename from the
     * command line.
     *
     * @param args[] Command line arguments, the first of which should be the
     * filename to open.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int runny = 1;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            new Maze(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Usage: java Maze <filename>.");
            System.out.println("Maximum Maze size:" + MAX_WIDTH + " x " + MAX_HEIGHT + ".");
            System.out.println();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the starting location and passes it to the recursive algorithm
     * solve(x, y, facing). The starting location should be the only '.' on the
     * outer wall of the maze.
     */
    public void solveMaze() throws FileNotFoundException {
        boolean startFound = false;
        if (!startFound) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {       // look for the starting location on the top and bottom walls of the Maze.
                if (maze[0][i] == '.') {
                    maze[0][i] = 'S';
                    steps[0][i]++;
                    preSolve(i, 0, "south");
                    startFound = true;
                } else if (maze[height - 1][i] == '.') {
                    maze[height - 1][i] = 'S';
                    steps[height - 1][i]++;
                    preSolve(i, height - 1, "north");
                    startFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!startFound) {
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {      // look for the starting location on the left and right walls of the Maze.
                if (maze[i][0] == '.') {
                    maze[i][0] = 'S';
                    steps[i][0]++;
                    preSolve(0, i, "east");
                    startFound = true;
                } else if (maze[i][width - 1] == '.') {
                    maze[i][width - 1] = 'S';
                    steps[i][width - 1]++;
                    preSolve(width - 1, i, "west");
                    startFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!startFound) {
            System.out.println("Start not found!");
        }
    }

    public void preSolve(int x, int y, String facing) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Press 1 to start");
        input.nextLine();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        solve(x, y, facing);
    }

    /**
     * Recursive algorithm to solve a Maze. Places an X at locations already
     * visited. This algorithm is very inefficient, it follows the right hand
     * wall and will never find the end if the path leads it in a circle.
     *
     * @param x int value of the current X location in the Maze.
     * @param y int value of the current Y location in the Maze.
     * @param facing String value holding one of four cardinal directions
     * determined by the current direction facing.
     */
    private void solve(int x, int y, String facing) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) mazePanel.getGraphics(); //don't mess with the next 

        while (!timerFired) {   // wait for the timer.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        timerFired = false;
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((currentTime - startTime) > MAX_TIME) {
            closingMethod();
        }

        if (maze[y][x] != 'F') {  //this is if it doesn't find the finish on a turn.........
            g2.drawImage(mazeImage, null, 0, 0);
            g2.drawImage(printGuy(facing), x * SPRITE_WIDTH, y * SPRITE_HEIGHT, null, null);
            mazePanel.setSize(width * SPRITE_WIDTH + 10, height * SPRITE_HEIGHT + 30);
            maze[y][x] = 'X';   // mark this spot as visited. This is how you can keep track of where you've been. 

            if (facing.equals("east")) {
                if (maze[y + 1][x] != '#' && maze[y + 1][x] != '%' && maze[y + 1][x] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y+1, x)) {
                    steps[y + 1][x]++;
                    solve(x, y + 1, "south");
                } else if (maze[y][x + 1] != '#' && maze[y][x + 1] != '%' && maze[y][x + 1] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y, x+1)) {
                    steps[y][x + 1]++;
                    solve(x + 1, y, "east");
                } else {
                    solve(x, y, "north");
                }
            } else if (facing.equals("west")) {
                if (maze[y - 1][x] != '#' && maze[y - 1][x] != '%' && maze[y - 1][x] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y-1, x)) {
                    steps[y - 1][x]++;
                    solve(x, y - 1, "north");
                } else if (maze[y][x - 1] != '#' && maze[y][x - 1] != '%' && maze[y][x - 1] != 'S'&& !hasBadBranch(y, x-1)) {
                    steps[y][x - 1]++;
                    solve(x - 1, y, "west");
                } else {
                    solve(x, y, "south");
                }
            } else if (facing.equals("south")) {
                if (maze[y][x - 1] != '#' && maze[y][x - 1] != '%' && maze[y][x - 1] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y, x-1)) {
                    steps[y][x - 1]++;
                    solve(x - 1, y, "west");
                } else if (maze[y + 1][x] != '#' && maze[y + 1][x] != '%' && maze[y + 1][x] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y+1, x)) {
                    steps[y + 1][x]++;
                    solve(x, y + 1, "south");
                } else {
                    solve(x, y, "east");
                }
            } else if (facing.equals("north")) {
                if (maze[y][x + 1] != '#' && maze[y][x + 1] != '%' && maze[y][x + 1] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y, x+1)) {
                    steps[y][x + 1]++;
                    solve(x + 1, y, "east");
                } else if (maze[y - 1][x] != '#' && maze[y - 1][x] != '%' && maze[y - 1][x] != 'S' && !hasBadBranch(y-1, x)) {
                    steps[y - 1][x]++;
                    solve(x, y - 1, "north");
                } else {
                    solve(x, y, "west");
                }
            }

        } else {
            writeToFile();
            System.out.println("Found the finish!");

            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long endTime = currentTime - startTime;
            long finalTime = endTime / 1000;
            System.out.println("Final Time = " + finalTime);

        }
    }

    public boolean hasBadBranch(int y, int x) {
        //9999 will be used to tell character not to take that branch
        if (steps[y][x] > 1) {
            if (steps[y + 1][x] > 1) {
                steps[y + 1][x] = 9999;
                return true;    //south
            }
            if (steps[y - 1][x] > 1) {
                steps[y - 1][x] = 9999;
                return true;    //north
            }
            if (steps[y][x + 1] > 1) {
                steps[y][x + 1] = 9999;
                return true;    //east
            }
            if (steps[y][x - 1] > 1) {
                steps[y][x - 1] = 9999;
                return true;    //west
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Opens a text file containing a maze and stores the data in the 2D char
     * array maze[][].
     *
     * @param fname String value containing the file name of the maze to open.
     */
    public void openMaze(String fname) {
        String in = "";
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fname));
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                in = sc.nextLine();
                in = trimWhitespace(in);
                if (in.length() <= MAX_WIDTH && i < MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < in.length(); j++) {
                        if (in.charAt(j) == '#') {      // if this spot is a wall, randomize the wall peice to display
                            if (random.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                                maze[i][j] = '#';
                            } else {
                                maze[i][j] = '%';
                            }
                        } else {
                            maze[i][j] = in.charAt(j);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Maximum maze size exceeded: (" + MAX_WIDTH + " x " + MAX_HEIGHT + ")!");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                i++;
            }
            width = in.length();
            height = i;
            System.out.println("(" + width + " x " + height + ") maze opened.");
            System.out.println();
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes white space from the supplied string and returns the trimmed
     * String.
     *
     * @param s String value to strip white space from.
     * @return String stripped of white space.
     */
    public String trimWhitespace(String s) {
        String newString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                newString += s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return newString;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the sprite facing the direction supplied.
     *
     * @param facing String value containing 1 of 4 cardinal directions to make
     * the sprite face.
     * @return Image of the sprite facing the proper direction.
     */
    private Image printGuy(String facing) {
        if (facing.equals("south")) {  // draw sprite facing south
            if (step) {
                step = false;
                return south1.getImage();
            } else {
                step = true;
                return south2.getImage();
            }
        } else if (facing.equals("north")) {  // draw sprite facing north
            if (step) {
                step = false;
                return north1.getImage();
            } else {
                step = true;
                return north2.getImage();
            }
        } else if (facing.equals("east")) {  // draw sprite facing east
            if (step) {
                step = false;
                return east1.getImage();
            } else {
                step = true;
                return east2.getImage();
            }
        } else if (facing.equals("west")) {  // draw sprite facing west
            if (step) {
                step = false;
                return west1.getImage();
            } else {
                step = true;
                return west2.getImage();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the Maze using sprites.
     *
     * @return BufferedImage rendition of the maze.
     */
    public BufferedImage printMaze() {
        BufferedImage mi = new BufferedImage(width * SPRITE_WIDTH, height * SPRITE_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g2 = mi.createGraphics();

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if (maze[i][j] == '#') {    // draw wall
                    g2.drawImage(wall1.getImage(), j * SPRITE_WIDTH, i * SPRITE_HEIGHT, null, null);
                } else if (maze[i][j] == '%') {   // draw wall
                    g2.drawImage(wall2.getImage(), j * SPRITE_WIDTH, i * SPRITE_HEIGHT, null, null);
                } else if (maze[i][j] == '.' || maze[i][j] == 'X') {  // draw ground
                    g2.drawImage(ground.getImage(), j * SPRITE_WIDTH, i * SPRITE_HEIGHT, null, null);
                } else if (maze[i][j] == 'F') {   // draw finish
                    g2.drawImage(finish.getImage(), j * SPRITE_WIDTH, i * SPRITE_HEIGHT, null, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return mi;
    }

    public void writeToFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("steps.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                printWriter.print(steps[i][j] + " ");
            }
            printWriter.println();
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }

    public void closingMethod() {
        long endTime = currentTime - startTime;
        long finalTime = endTime / 100;
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private class TimerHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timerFired = true;
        }
    }

    private class WindowHandler extends WindowAdapter {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            removeAll();
            closingMethod();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to solve a maze this way? This won't give you the optimal answer. You should use breadth-first search instead.

Comment: My professor gave us this general outline for solving the maze 3 times, each time saving what you learn, so with the third trial you can solve it  by taking the direct path.

Comment: I understand how breadth-first search works, but how would you apply it to a maze like this? @Haozhun

Comment: @CSstudent Hey, so what's your question? Do you know what needs to be saved to the file? I see an `openMaze` method, but it seems like you are not saving anything yet?

Comment: @CSstudent btw, without the input file as well as the image resources, we can't actually run your program and see what you are doing. Can you narrow down your question to a specific problem?

Comment: It was recommended that we write/save the maze to the file with the path that the character took marked

Comment: I am saving the maze to a file, showing the first run through where I've moved.  On the second run, I will open that file, but how can I use that information to decrease the unnecessary paths taken to reach the finish? @Gosu

Comment: If the professor asked specifically for this solution, my question would be off-topic. To apply BFS, consider every point on the maze as a vertex, and add an edge between two adjacent point (vertex) if neither is #.

Comment: you're probably trying to look at array index -1 while your function is along the top/left wall. you start at (0, something), and none of your functions check for -1 or height+1 boundary cases.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you did was to solve the maze using DFS with a fixed exploration rule (right hand). The info you should save is the number of times you stepped on a square. when you hit a dead end you will be going back to the intersection to try another branch.

So on the second solving, when you find an intersection with a score > 1, you should modify the explore rule to avoid branches that have score > 1 (1 means u never had to come back == previous solution path, 2 (or more) means you had to come back after a dead-end (or a few)). Hope that made sense.

Comment: Wouldn't BFS find the shortest solution faster?

Comment: Thanks @softwarenewbie7331.  I'm trying to make a method that checks an intersection and sees if any of its branches are > 1, and if so, returns true.  What I have doesn't seem to be working (array out of bounds, character doesn't correctly move through maze anymore).  Do see any flaws in my logic?
public boolean badIntersection(int y, int x) { 
 if (steps[y][x] > 1) {
  if (steps[y + 1][x] > 1) {
   steps[y + 1][x] = 9999; //marks a path that should not be taken
   return true;      //south
  }
  ...
 }
}

Comment: And in my solve method I'm adding:
if (facing.equals("east")) {
    if (maze[y + 1][x] != '#' && maze[y + 1][x] != '%') && !isBadIntersection(y+1, x)) {
        steps[y + 1][x]++;
        solve(x, y + 1, "south");
    } else if (maze[y][x + 1] != '#' && maze[y][x + 1] != '%' && !isBadIntersection(y, x+1)) {
        steps[y][x + 1]++;
        solve(x + 1, y, "east");
    } else {
        solve(x, y, "north");
    }
 ...
}

Comment: you should put this in the question so other people can read/help. Out of bounds is obviously because you need to check for right and bottom boundaries. Not sure what the second comment code is doing. 
@M.Shaw I'm assuming he's stuck using what his prof wanted (sth like dfs)